# Regular expression to detect the search engine and search words

Tags: regex, search-engine

I need to detect search engines that refers to my website. Since every search engine has different query strings for searching(e.g. google uses 'q=', yahoo uses 'p=') I created a database for search engines with their url regex patterns.

As an example:
http://www.google.com/search?q=blabla&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

the regex I created for google is:

```
(http:)(\\/)(\\/)(www)(\\.)(google)(\\.).*(\\/)(search).*(&q=|\\?q=).*
```

(I am a newbie on regex, but so far it works)

This detects that the url belongs to Google.
My problem is that I need to extract the search words from the url above or from other search engines. But I dont know how to match it with the regular expression. I have tried extracting the query string from the url by using PHP functions and match it against the pattern, but it returned nothing.

Hope I could explain this clear enough.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You don’t need to put each single character in a group. This will suffice: `/http:\/\/www\.google\..*\/search.*(&q=|\?q=).*/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog entry about extracting keywords from the referrer](http://www.istanto.net/phpcatching-keyword-from-search-engine.html) seems like it is a good match for solving your problem.

I found it using this [search for 'extract query string from google referer url'](http://www.google.com/search?q=extract+query+string+from+google+referer+url).  The search seems to have a number of helpful hits... I just did a sweep of the first few.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) to parse the URL and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) to parse the URL query.

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=blabla&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&client=firefox-a';
$parts = parse_url($url);
if (isset($parts['query'])) {
    parse_str($parts['query'], $parts['query']);
}
var_dump($parts);
```

Comment: Yes but there are many query strings in the url. I have to detect the search words but which query string contains the search words? q= or p=. My plan was extracting the query by using the functions that you have mentioned and match it against the pattern to detect the query string that contains the search words.

Comment: @Ahmet Keskin: Detect what search engine is given (examine `$parts['host']`) and then get the associated query argument.