# Regular expression to capture Google search term from URL

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following URL (which is the result of a Google search in Firefox followed by changing the search terms once via Google's interface which adds the part starting with the `#`):

```
https://www.google.de/search?q=initial+search+term&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Zw_rVfjrMMj8abKsn0g#q=changed+search+terms
```

How do I write a RegExp (JavaScript) that captures `"changed+search+terms"` if present in the URL but `"initial+search+terms" by default?

Also it should be flexible enough to support different TLDs and accept the `"q=search+terms"` part at different positions in the URL.

So far I have

```
^https?://([^.]+\.)?google\.([a-z]+\.?)+/[^?/]*\?(.*&)?q=([^&]+)
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to prefer the second `"q="` if present.

Comment: Why does it have to be a single regex?

Comment: `\.([a-z]+\.?)+` should probably be `(?:\.[a-z]+)+`.

Comment: The way your regex is written, you can probably get away with changing `.*&` to `.*[&#]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to detect the search engine and search words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963883/regular-expression-to-detect-the-search-engine-and-search-words)

Comment: Single regex is needed because it is needed inside another application.

What's the difference between `\.([a-z]+\.?)+` and `(?:\.[a-z]+)+`?

Replacing `.*&` with `.*[&#]` seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

You could use replace to find the values if they exist. This will trim some extra checking off your regex so all you need to do is search for the ?q= or #q= parts of the URL.

```
var found = ""

var s = "https://www.google.de/search?q=initial+search+term&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Zw_rVfjrMMj8abKsn0g#q=changed+search+terms"

s.replace(/\?q=([^&#]+)|#q=([^&]+)/, function(m,a,b){
  found = (typeof a === "undefined") ? b : a;
});

console.log(found)
```